# Is there a way to move the description of the ID through a JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am working with two tables (question and question_typ) and im trying to get the definition of the question over without hard coding in case it changes. Is there a way to do this through a join?

Here are the tables:

question:

| Code | q_resp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Question table keeps messing up, here is a screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utERl.png)

question_typ

| Code | Desc | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bad | 1 |
| 1 | So-So | 2 |
| 1 | Good | 3 |
| 1 | Great | 4 |
| 1 | Best | 5 |
| 2 | Home | 1 |
| 2 | School | 2 |
| 2 | Store | 3 |
| 2 | Work | 4 |
| 2 | Car | 5 |

I have already Pivoted the columns so that the codes run at the top and the values are below so the table looks like this now:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |

But how do I get the description of the values under each code, especially since the "value" columns don't have the same name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to joij both tables, with the columns that connects both tables

```
SELECT q.code, q.q_resp AS response, qt.Desc as description
FROM question q
JOIN question_typ qt
    ON q.code = qt.code and q.q_resp  = qt.value
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say to say without knowing the output you're looking for (if you had included some SQL in your question, that could have helped too), but this should get you the question code, the response, and the description. Haven't tested it.

```sql
SELECT q.code, q.q_resp AS response, qt.Desc as description
FROM question q
JOIN question_typ qt
    ON q.code = qt.code
```

Basically, we're just joining quesion.code on question_type.code & returning the desired columns.